# check if value exist in each array multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

i hava multidimensional array

```
     <?php

$data = array(
array(
'name'=>'ahmed',
'job'=>'engineer',
'age'=>25,
'hobbies' => array('drawing','swimming','reading'),
'skills' => array('coding','fasting learning','teaching')
),
array(
'name'=>'Sara',
'job'=>'designer',
'age'=>19,
'skills'=>array('fast learning')
) ,
array(
'name'=>'Ali',
'age'=>25,
'city'=>'cairo'
),

array(
'name'=>'Hossam',
'job'=>'accountant',
'age'=>25,
'city'=>'zagazig'
),
array(
'name'=>'Esraa',
'job'=>'Designer',
'age'=>23,
'city'=>'zagazig',
'hobbies' => array('writing','reading'),
'skills' => array('coding','teaching')
),
);
```

i want count Arrays where city = "zagazig" or "cairo"

and echo Array Values

> Example :
>
> - There is [ 1 ] people of City => [ cairo ] :
>
> ---------------- Result -----------------------
>
> - Name => Ali
> - Age => 25
> - City => cairo
>
> ---

if City `!exist` echo Values

> Example :
>
> *---------------- Invaild Data -------------
>
> ----------------------- First ---------------
>
> - Name => Sara
> - Job => designer
> - Age => 19
> - Skill => fast learning
>
> ----------------- Second ----------------
>
> - Name => ahmed
> - Job => engineer
> - Age => 25
>
> -------------------- Hobbies ----------------
>
> - drawing
> - swimming
> - reading
>
> -------------------- Skills ----------------
>
> - coding
> - fasting learning
> - teaching
>
> ---

but i don't know how to loop Multidimensional Array

Comment: where did you get the data?, if this if from a db layer, why not do it from there instead. if not, just use a `foreach`

Comment: You don't know how to loop a Multidimensional Array :O :O

Comment: I have tried and searched for answers , the last thing i do ask someone :D i found this      foreach($data[4] as $array)
{
    echo $array;
}

Comment: i want now know how to count all arrays where city = value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is just a raw array, a simple `if` with `foreach` should suffice.

First, if the criteria is to get certain entries using `city`, just use a `stripos` to search;

```
$search_string = 'zagazig';
$results = array();
foreach($data as $value) {
    if(
        !empty($value['city']) &&
        (stripos($value['city'], $search_string) !== false)
    ) {
        $results[] = $value;
    }
}
```

This checks if the entry has a city index, then just pushes that array inside a container `$result`. After gathering the results, just loop it like any normal array:

```
if(!empty($results)) {
    echo 'Number of results: ' , count($results), '<br/> Result <hr/>';
    foreach($results as $r) {
        echo "
        Name: {$r['name']}
        Job: {$r['job']}
        Age: {$r['age']} <br/>
        ";
        echo !empty($r['hobbies']) ? '<br/>Hobbies: <br/>' . implode('<br/>', $r['hobbies']) : '';
    }
}
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/cMom5)

Of course you can use a `<table>` tag if you want, this is just an ugly example.

If you like something a little bit different, you can also use `array_filter`:

Here's an example of it (this also includes some searching inside `hobbies` and `skills`):

```
$search_string = 'coding';
$criteria = 'skills';
$results = array_filter($data, function($e) use ($search_string, $criteria) { 
    return (
        !empty($e[$criteria]) && 
        (!is_array($e[$criteria]) 
            ? (strpos($e[$criteria], $search_string) !== false)
            : (in_array($search_string, $e[$criteria]))
        )
    );
});
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/3vCFe)

Answer (score 0):

Use php foreach() like:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
{
    statement
}
```

[Foreach Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)